# How to switch between two types in Kotlin

Tags: android, class, kotlin

It might be a really simple question but I don't know how to deal with it.
I have an open class called "User". This class gets -among others- a propriety named "role".

This role can either be A or B - which are personal defined classes

How can I set it up in my Kotlin User class, please?

```
open class User (
    var email : String = "",
    var role : ???
)

class A : User() {
    var name : String = ""
}

class B : User() {
    var color : String = ""
}
```

Comment: A or B are the child classes from User. I'm gonna go with a Role interface. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what its called a generic or a parametrized data type, I think the best for the implementation is to leverage `abstract` classes for the parent and then for the child `data` classes

```
abstract class User<RoleType> (
    var email : String = "",
    abstract var role : RoleType
)

data class A(override var role: SomeClassOfYou) : User<SomeClassOfYou>()

data class B(override var role: AnotherClassOfYou) : User<AnotherClassOfYou>()
```

The problem with the above is you are basically saying, that your `RoleType` is `any` which ranges from `Int` to whatever class exists, so it is better to have another type to delimit it, an `interface` by example.

```
interface RoleType {
    //add your methods
}
```

Then that way we can constraint the type to `RoleType` interface and any implementation will be valid

```
abstract class User<Type : RoleType> (
    var email : String = "",
    abstract var role : RoleType
)

//Assuming there is a Foreman class that implements RoleType
data class A(override var role: Foreman) : User<Foreman>()

//... the other class
```

Another thing you should be aware if that the `role` is just a category and the interface implementing it would have no methods, then using an enum is better

```
enum class UserRole {
    Foreman,
    Worker
}

abstract class User<Type : RoleType> (
    var email : String = "",
    abstract var role : UserRole
)
```

And the last thing, consider using a sealed class in conjunction with enum well:

```
sealed class User(
    var email : String = "",
    open var role : UserRole
) {

    //Making the child classes inner can use the parent class as a domain naming
    data class Foreman(val email: String, override var role: UserRole) : User(email, role)

}
```

Comment: My first thought was to use Enum. But I had no idea how to do the connection between the Enum name (Foreman or Worker in your case) and my data class Foreman (or Worker). It seems like you answered it for me :)

Answer (score 2):

An interface might work, but your `A` and `B` classes have different properties, so there isn't really anything in common to put in a shared interface. You'd need separate ones, `RoleA` and `RoleB`, so you can do things like `if (user is RoleB) print(user.color)`.

You can already do that with your code (`if (user is B) print(user.color)`) but it's a composition vs inheritance thing - it might be better to just subclass user like you're doing, or it might be better to add interfaces to stack different behaviours - depends what you're doing and which is least complicated!

---

If you do want to keep `role` as a property instead of making it a *type* that `User` has (so `if (user.role is RoleA)` rather than `if (user is RoleA)`) you might want to look at [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html):

```
sealed class Role {
    data class A(var name: String = "") : Role()
    data class B(var color: String = "") : Role()
}
```

then you can have

```
class User {
    var email: String = "",
    val role: Role
}
```

The sealed class basically acts as a group of types - the classes and objects inside can all be completely different, they don't need to share any common methods and properties or anything. But because you're defining the `Role` class as those things (and only those things), you can check which specific type a `Role` is, and you can do exhaustive pattern matching too:

```
when(role) {
    is Role.A -> print(role.name)
    is Role.B -> print(role.color)
}
```

and it knows you've covered all the possible cases. So you can make each `Role` class whatever you want, and treat each one accordingly. It might be a bit neater than using and implementing interfaces!

Comment: I want to thank you. so. much. I needed these explanations and you made it very clear. This is exactly what I needed to use in my application. Again, thank you for your time and making it easy for me to understand!

Comment: Hey no problem! I was worried it might be complicating things a bit, but I wanted to give you some stuff to look into too. Good luck!

Comment: it does not complicate anything. You taught me something new: Sealed class. Thank you and happy coding :)

Comment: Oh while I'm at it - I used ``var``s since you were using them in your code, but unless you definitely need to change the values, it's better to use ``val``s. Saves you a lot of headaches and Kotlin going "oh hey maybe this value has changed now hmmm?" If you're using data classes there's a ``copy`` method that lets you specify some new parameter values, so it's like changing them. Up to you and what you're doing but I just wanted to mention it!

Comment: Was worth it! I knew about this point but I honestly didn't pay attention when I first exposed my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Any` keyword to hold the `class` object reference and I also recommend you to use the interface suggested by @deHaar

```
open class User (
        var email : String = "",
        var role : Any
    )

    class A : User("",A()) {
        var name : String = ""
    }

    class B : User("",B()) {
        var color : String = ""
    }
```